# how to debug inconsistent failure

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, power-supply, windows-11

I have a strange issue. I got a new pc, assembled it, installed everything, all works great. With the small note that randomly my screen flashes a couple of times.

Initially I thought it is a power issue but the power supply should hold quite well (Sursa Seasonic PRIME TX-1000, 80+ Titanium, 1000W), single gpu (GeForce RTX 3090 Ti GAMING OC 24GB GDDR6X 384-bit), with an Core i9 12900K 3.2GHz box cpu.

If my math is correct, it should never go over 800W (including the fans). Tried to test it anyway, I just ran everything I had that could drain power and had 0 issues (I'm thinking that if power was a problem, it would've gotten worse under load; that didn't happen).

Then I thought it maybe is some gpu issue... but it handles everything perfectly (over 120 fps in everything, all looks great - except the random flicker obviously).

Then I thought it may be a driver issue. So I uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers. And the problem... went away. Used the pc for like 2h with no issues... then just when I was about to call it a day... did it again 3 times.

Temperatures look ok overall (highest is the cpu - 78 celsius in full load).

Note: Tested with 2 different monitors, happens for both so I don't think is the monitor.

Note 2: I do have some failures in event viewer but they seem rather unrelated (The event logging service encountered an error while processing an incoming event published from Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing.).

I am stuck... have no idea how to go on. Any hints?

Comment: You really should test your cables next.

Comment: Switched cables when I switched monitors.